# What kinds of things can cause ngSanitize to throw a Parse Error

Tags: angularjs

I have an AngularJS app that parses HTML which largely comes from emails.  In some cases data-bind-html will throw a Parse Error but not all cases.  I've been unable to determine why.

Does anyone know some types of tokens or syntax that can cause the error?

Here's a sample of a file which trips it up:

> ,
>   
>   
>   I received the following error message...:
>
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from
>
> ### fulfilling the request.
>
> HTTP_Status = 500 (Internal Server Error)
>
> URL =
>
> ----------------------------------------- Request Headers 
>   ----------------------------------------- POST /ss/servlet/FooServlet/ HTTP/1.1 Accept: Accept: */* Host: mydomain.org Content-Length: 141
>   User-Agent: FooBar/2.1.94 Pragma: no-cache Cache-Control: no-cache
>   Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset="utf-8"
>   Connection: Keep-Alive Cookie:
>   BIGipServerpool_cookie_apps_ss_8188=rd860o00000000000000000000ffff0a0ad0aco8188;
>   JSESSIONID=5215F941A173B6127E9A95B3E99E3A74
>
> ----------------------------------------- Response Headers 
>   ----------------------------------------- HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1 Set-Cookie:
>   JSESSIONID=A9B7C98E5359D961DC8958F87CCCF49E; Path=/ss
>   Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="spreadsheet.csv"
>   Content-Description: spreadsheet.csv Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
>   Content-Type: application/csv;charset=ISO-8859-1 Transfer-Encoding:
>   chunked Date: Wed, 06 Mar 2013 18:46:19 GMT Connection: close
>
> -------------...

Comment: To get the answer, try to reproduce this in plunker.

Comment: Here is a plunker from your provided data that doesn't cause an error: http://plnkr.co/edit/imoSOemTl8qXu2jbscDR?p=preview

I suggest that you take whatever file is causing the error and cut it in half, if that is still giving an error then cut it in half again, until you find what is causing the error.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions so far.. I'm still debugging this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Emails can contain a lot of arbitrary encoding and invalid HTML, such as `<email@domain.com>`. To eliminate the Parse Errors I've implemented my own filter which takes effect before it goes through ngSanitize/bind-html.

`ng-bind-html="obj.emailContent | sanitizeEmail"`

```
myModule.filter('sanitizeEmail', function() {
  return function(input) {
    return input.replace(/<[\w-]*\.[\w-]*>/g, '').replace(/<[\w\.\$-]+[\:@].*>/g, '');
  };
});
```